# assigning value with pointer/array difference

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

as a beginner of C, I am still confused by the concept of magical "pointer"

For example, it is a simple code that store one to ten in the array "range1"

```
int *range1;
int max = 10;
int count = 0;
range1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * (11));
while (count < max)
{
    range1[count] = count;
    count++;
}
range1[count] = '\0';
```

this is working great, but

```
int *range1;
int max = 10;
int count = 0;
range1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * (11));
while (count < max)
{
    *range1 = count;
    count++;
    range1++;
} 
range1[count] = '\0';
```

this one is not. i get

```
[1]    24934 segmentation fault
```

I am confused because I thought *(range1 + count) = range1[count].

How can I change the second example so it runs without generating a segmentation violation.

Comment: range1[11] = '\0'; out-of-bounds write.  Last valid index is 10.

Comment: You didn't say what is "not working" in the second example, which is equivalent. Is the problem in code you did not show? Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane The OP used `range1` after the loop, and it doesn't work because it has been moved forward unlike the first example.

Comment: @FeiXiang not in the second example which is why complete code should be posted.

Comment: @FeiXiang ?? where?

Comment: As @MartinJames points out, you are writing out of bounds.  You simply made an off-by-one error there and should be able to replace with `range1[10]`, or as `count` should be equal to `10` at the end of the loop, `range1[count]`.

Comment: @MartinJames my malloc size is 11 int, so wouldn't I still have 1 space after filling 10 ints?

Comment: OK, - you are guessing that the OP freed 'range1' after the loop.  That makes sense, and gets a down/close for not posting MCVE for both cases,  not explaining why the second snippet fails and not highlighting the line causing the error.

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry for not detailed answer I got segmentation fault

Comment: @MartinJames sorry. I didn't realized that I wrote like that. my original code is range1[count] = '\0'

Comment: @kimsihyeon 'so wouldn't I still have 1 space after filling 10 ints' yes, and it's at range1[10], not range1[11].  With your count loop, you load ten values at indices 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,

Comment: @kimsihyeon please put that in the code posted, not in a comment.

Comment: There is no magic in computers.

Answer (score 7):

Use of

```
range1++;
```

is not advised unless you have another variable that stores the value returned by `malloc`. Without such a variable, you lose the original pointer. Calling `free` will be a problem.

Also, if you continue to use

```
range1[11] = '\0';
```

after the loop, you are accessing and modifying a location in memory that you are not supposed to. That causes undefined behavior.

**PS**

Use of

```
range1[11] = '\0';
```

is a problem even if you use the first method of accessing the elements of `range1`. When you allocate 11 elements, 10 is the highest valid index.

Comment: That was an unlucky escape; the greater problem is what OP might be doing in the second example, after changing the pointer, which was not posted.

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes, that was an unlucky escape.

Comment: I am so sorry, I wrote the code wrongly when I copied here. it supposes to be "range1[count] == '\0'"

Comment: @kimsihyeon, Your comment underscore the case for always posting a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you tried to use range1 after incrementing it. You should keep a copy of the original pointer to print the array and free the memory.

See the code below with comments in-line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
  int *range1, *range2;
  int max = 10;
  int count = 0;

  range1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 11);
  range2 = range1;


  printf("\nstart Test 1 -- array\n");
  while (count < max)
  {
      range1[count] = count;
      count++;
  }
  range1[10] = '\0'; // index 11 is out of bounds
  // Also this is not something you'd usually do in with an array of integers.
  // It is commonly done with character arrays representing strings because
  // strings are NUL terminated.

  for(int i=0; i < max; i++) {
    printf("%d: %d\n", i, range1[i]);
  }

  printf("\nstart Test 2 -- ptr incr\n");

  range2 = range1; // need to work with a copy and keep range 1 to print and free memory

  while (count < max)
  {
    *range2 = count;
    count++;
    range2++;
  } 

  for(int i=0; i < max; i++) {
    printf("%d: %d\n", i, range1[i]);
  }
  free(range1);
}
```

Output:

```
start Test 1 -- array
0: 0
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
5: 5
6: 6
7: 7
8: 8
9: 9

start Test 2 -- ptr incr
0: 0
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
5: 5
6: 6
7: 7
8: 8
9: 9
```